# Should OAuth access token be hashed before storing in the DB server side?

Tags: hash, oauth, access-token

I am implementing an OAuth server that supports [Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) flow. Once I generate the access token should I hash the token before storing it in the DB? My main concern if I hash is, if the token request comes a second time after I have generated the token and associated it with the username/password combination, it would be impossible to send the token back as it has been hashed. Am I supposed to throw an error in that case? The RFC is silent about this.

Comment: Not sure what type of system you are working on here but it should be the refresh token you are saving access tokens are normally short lived.  That being said token is paired with client id without both of them no one can use the refresh token generated.

Comment: I am trying to keep things simple for now. My access tokens have lifetime validity. So I am not generating any refresh token.